# JQuery Carousel Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

I am using Carousel  jquery plugin in my application. I need to display a name. It shows the name properly in IE, but not in mozilla. 
Here is my code :

```
function mycarousel_itemVisibleInCallbackAfterAnimation(carousel, item, idx, state) { 
   if (document.getElementById("Id") != null) {
      if (item.all) {
         if (item.all[1]) {
            if (item.all[1].childNodes) {
               document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML =
                     item.all[1].childNodes[0].alt;
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
```

Can someone help me out.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? An code-example of your implementation would be nice.

Comment: function mycarousel_itemVisibleInCallbackAfterAnimation(carousel, item, idx, state) {
debugger
    if (document.getElementById("Id") != null) {
       if (item.all) {
            if (item.all[1]) {
                if (item.all[1].childNodes) {
                    document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML = item.all[1].childNodes[0].alt;
                }
              
            }
        }
   }
};

Comment: This is the code I am using. In IE it gets the value properly, but in mozilla it does not show the name. item.all is undefined. Can you please help me out of this problem.

Comment: you should edit your question for this and post the code there. This is more readable.

Comment: @Rob, Can you please tell me the regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have jQuery reference, why don't you just use it.

```
function mycarousel_itemVisibleInCallbackAfterAnimation(carousel, item, idx, state) { 
   if(jQuery('#' + idx)[0] && jQuery(item.all[1]).children()[0]){
     jQuery('#' + idx).html( jQuery(jQuery(item.all[1]).children()[0]).attr('alt'));
   }
};
```